# Constructor with initialized parameter in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

My instructor requires us to fill out the constructors associated with these prototypes:

```
YearToMonth(short years=0);
YearToMonth(short years, short months);
```

My question is: with the 1 parameter constructor, will the value passed in always = 0? I've never seen a function that assigned value to a parameter before. Seems kinda strange to require input when the value is just going to be set to zero but then I wasn't given any documentation on this class so I don't really know what it does yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [default argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). Its effect is to provide a default value if the user doesn't explicitly specify one. For example:

```
YearToMonth();   // calls YearToMonth(short ); with years=0
YearToMonth(2);  // calls YearToMonth(short ); with years=2
```

Comment: Except that the function is overloaded for 2 arguments but the idea is right.

Answer (score 0):

It's default value for the parameter. if you pass your own value to it, it will be set to your value.